# Intercept rules in spring secuirty

Tags: spring

Spring security configuration:

```
intercept-url pattern="/login.jsp*" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY"`
intercept-url pattern="/**" access="ROLE_USER" 
form-login login-page='/login.jsp'
```

I am new in spring security. I have some questions:

1. what is meaning of  "IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY"?
2. why there is error in it? (i read in documentation that there is error in it due to infinite loop.)
   If there are more intercept rules than how it will be evaluate?

Answer (score 1):

First things first.. Always Always always give anonymous access to your Login and Registration screens. ANONYMOUS= NO AUTHENTICATION REQUIRED. Failing to do so will never allow any user to use ur application and ur page will end up loading forever.. Also keep your static resources (CSS, JS, Images etc) away from security filters. In MOST of the cases these static resources never require security

This code snippet explains the above description:

```
<security:http pattern = "/css/**" security = "none"/>
    <security:http pattern = "/anonymous/**" security = "none"/>
    <security:http pattern = "/loginpage/**" security = "none"/>
    <security:http pattern = "/forgotpassword/**" security = "none"/>
    <security:http pattern = "/registerpage/**" security = "none"/>
    <security:http pattern = "/js/**" security = "none"/>
    <security:http pattern = "/images/**" security = "none"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

**IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY** - this is means anyone can access this page without logged in to your system.

**ROLE_USER** - Means only users who have ROLE = ROLE_USER can access those URLS that match with your pattern.

If There are more intercept rules than there are follow the same as above, one - by - one but ORDER OF THIS MATERS for the matching. If your first pattern match with your requested URL than it will not look for other. so during given intercept rules you need to take care of the order in which they are written.

Hope this help.

Answer (score 0):

> what is meaning of "IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY"?

this means anyone can access this page without logging in.

> why there is error in it?

You have an infinite loop because the login page should not be secured. The login page should not be secured for anyone to be able to enter it's credentials.